# Is there a way to hard delete an Apex Trigger when there is no Apex Class?

Tags: apex, class, delete

I had a developer work on this before myself, so I'm working backwards. I've been able to get all the coding I needed for my org, however, now I have two Inactive Apex Triggers sitting in the Sandbox and Production. I'd like to delete said triggers, but the force.com IDE and Workbench options both require deletion of the Apex Class, however, I do not see any classes related to these triggers. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to find mentions of these triggers thorough the source code in IDE, it may be referenced in test classes.

Comment: Could you [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/280100/edit) your question and add a screenshot of (or the exact text for) the specific error you get?

Comment: btw, the first thing I would do is actually empty the trigger out so it is an empty trigger with no code in it, set it inactive and then try to delete it.

Comment: @PhilW unfortunately I don't have an error, I just went to the Apex Classes to get the name and there's nothing in there related to them. But you make a valid point, I should just empty the inactive and push it through production... let me see how that pans out. It's not necessarily the cleanest but may help. Thanks!

Comment: @PhilW Well clearing out the code and pushing to production worked (removed the total Apex usage), however it would be nice to know how to hard delete in the future when there is no class

Comment: I think the point is that the "class" is the code content of the Apex Trigger. That it says there is a class is likely just misleading terminology related to the way Apex classes and triggers are very similar in content (if not structure). I would say that simply emptying the trigger should be enough to hard-delete, and if not you could always try setting the status in the meta XML file for the trigger to Deleted. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_triggers.htm

Comment: Thank you, @PhilW